# Can I override setter function of generic class?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overriding

I am inheriting generic class Vehicle in generic class Jet with two more variable named T4 and T5. While overriding `setName(T )` function of parent class I get an error saying `Error:(27, 17) java: name clash: setName(T1) in Jet and setName(T1) in Vehicle have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other`

```
class Vehicle <T1,T2,T3 extends Number>{
 private T1 name;
 private T2 company;
 private T3 price;
 public void setName(T1 name){
     this.name=name;
 } 
 public void setCompany(T2 company){
     this.company=company;
 }
 public void setPrice(T3 price){
     this.price=price;
 }
 public T1 getName(){
     return name;
 }
 public T2 getCompany(){
     return company;
 }
 public T3 getPrice(){
     return price;
 }
}
class Jet <T5,T2,T3,T4> extends Vehicle{
 T4 jetEngine;
 T5 name;
 public void setName(T5 name){ //causing an error here
     this.name = name;
     System.out.println("Yeah you can do that");
 }
 public void setJetEngine(T4 jetEngine){
     this.jetEngine=jetEngine;
 }
 public T4 getJetEngine(){
     return jetEngine;
 }
```

}

Comment: You're extending `Vehicle` as a raw type. Did you mean something like `extends Vehicle<T5, T2, T3>` ?

Comment: Yes I want to change T1 with T5 and setName(T5 obj)

Comment: Please edit your question to fix that, if that's your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're extendingVehicle as a raw type. So setName() will not take T5 as an argument. If you want to override setName(T1) with setname(T5) you should do something like

```
class Jet<T5, T2, T3 extends Number, T4> extends Vehicle<T5, T2, T3> {

    ....

    public void setName(T5 name) {
        // this should work now
    }

    ....
}
```

The generic Parameters T1, T2, T3 don't mean anything to the parent class if you do not pass them to the parent class as well. They will simply be seen as raw types and java will expect them all to be `Object`.